# Can I update the adb shell's environment variables?

Tags: adb, mksh

I wanted to update the `PATH` environment variable permanently in the **adb shell**. I guessed the shell was `mksh` for I've found `/system/bin/sh` pointing to `/system/bin/mksh`. Then I tried

- Making a new file `/data/.mkshrc` and adding the `PATH` definition into it.
- Copy the above file into `/`.
- Copy to `/root`.

But all attempts failed.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to [what Alex-p wrote](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/53423/55417), you can also set the `ENV` environment variable to override the path of the `mkshrc` file used.

All login shells also read `/system/etc/profile` and `$HOME/.profile` (these are a good place to `export ENV`). Apparently (for some reason that defies my ability to explain), `adb shell` does not start a login shell¹, though, so `/system/etc/mkshrc` *is* the file you will have to change for that.

(Disclaimer: I’m the [`mksh`](https://www.mirbsd.org/mksh.htm) maintainer.)

① I’d expect “adb shell” to behave like ssh and start login shells if there is no explicit command given, as it *does* start a (new) session every time it’s run. Subshells will be interactive but not login shells, of course. But this is not the place to discuss that… if I care I’ll take it up at AOSP via Gerrit.

Answer (score 8):

By default [stock Android `mksh`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/mksh/+/master/Android.mk) uses this config file: `/system/etc/mkshrc`

Answer (score 3):

To update the PATH variable inside a running `adb shell` you can use the `expect` command. This works on a non-rooted phone where you can't edit system files as suggested in the other answers.

Put the following script somewhere on the path of your development machine, for example in `~/bin/adb-shell-busybox`:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect --
spawn adb shell
expect "$" {
    sleep 0.1
    send "export PATH=/data/data/burrows.apps.busybox/app_busybox/:\$PATH\n"
}
interact
```

You can also inject any other setup commands that you might need.