# Shell .profile or /etc/profile for old android 2.3.3

Tags: shell, mksh

Just rooted my old phone with Android 2.3.3 and I would like to define some aliases for each shell I start (with adb or terminal app). I found [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/53389/126176) where one answer says that `/etc/profile` (=`/system/etc/profile` due to soft link `/etc`->`/system/etc`) is one of the files the shell sources on startup. But this post talks about `/system/bin/sh` being a link to `/system/bin/mksh`, which is not the case on my 2.3.3 system.

Despite the fact that `strings sh` produces `/etc/profile` as one output, the file is not sourced.

Does anyone happen to know the old Android version and whether I have a chance to get /etc/profile or some other file sourced on shell startup? I thought it might be a permission problem but even rwxrwxr-x does not help.

Answer (score 4):

As [I wrote in the other question](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/64926/55417), `adb shell` does *not* start a login shell. Only login shells read `/etc/profile`.

As you can see in [Android 2.3.3 sh source, `main.c` lines 175ﬀ.](https://github.com/android/platform_system_core/blob/android-2.3.3_r1/sh/main.c#L175) only if `argv[0]` starts with a hyphen-minus is the shell considered a login shell. However, a few lines below (lines 185ﬀ.) there is code to read the content of `$ENV`.

So you could trick it and enter the following code after entering `adb shell` mode:

```
ENV=/etc/profile sh
```

You can probably use `exec` to replace the current shell, but this is the shortest to type I can come up with, as you *will* have to type it every time.

---

Alternatively, you can compile `mksh` for Android 2.3 (it works down to at least 1.5, if not older) manually (the Android.mk file is version-specific, unfortunately, so you’ll have to call Build.sh directly) and add the binary, then replace the default `sh` with it (I tested that first with Android 1.6; the newer the mksh version used the better, as early versions had bugs, e.g. preventing `adb install` from working).

Disclaimer: I’m the [mksh](http://www.mirbsd.org/mksh.htm) developer.